# efficient alternative to BitmapFactory.decode call?

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I have to render a Image, for that I have to first decode a image and then load it on to GPU. BitmapFactory.decode_() call is taking so much time. Can anyone suggest some other technique?

Comment: Try this link(http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). Also you should explain better your problem, size of the image, are you downloading the image from a server , etc

Comment: I have to render a image on glSurfaceView I have a image stored in my res folder. I am using command BitmapFactory.decodeResources() to decode a jpeg image. then loading the image to gpu using glTex2D  command. this decode command is taking around 150 millisecond which I want to reduce. Image is a FULL HD image(1920*1080).

Comment: There is any limitation about the os version?

Comment: Want for android 4.4